# NullPointerException for object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have the following constructor:

```
public Question(String text) {
    this.totalPossibleSelections = 1;
    this.text = text;
    this.currentSelections = new QuestionElement[1];
    this.finalSelections = new QuestionElement[1];
}
```

and this method in the same class:

```
public void setCurrentSelection(QuestionElement selection) {
    if (totalPossibleSelections == 1){
        currentSelections[0] = selection;
    }
}
```

where

```
protected QuestionElement[] currentSelections;
```

is one of the parameter of my object `Question`.

`currentSelections` is `null` when I call `setCurrentSelection` which is causing a `NullPointerException`.  `currentSelections` shouldn't be null because the method `setCurrentSelection` can only operate on a Question.  I have initialized my `Question` by calling the constructor in another piece of code.  What might be going on here?

EDIT:
There are no subclasses of `Question`.  Also the constructor is being called.  If it wasn't, `totalPossibleSelections` would be `null`.

Comment: If you are sure this constructor is being called, you should verify that you are not nullifying `currentSelections` anywhere else in your class.

Comment: Set breakpoint where U are initialize your array and run debug mode.

Comment: Is there inheritance? Is currentSelections part of a base class, or what do you mean with "parameter of my object Question?" Another constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps because `QuestionElement[]` is `protected` - is a sub class setting it to null.

Change to `protected final QuestionElement[] currentSelections` to avoid confusion **then** it can't be null

Comment: There are no subclasses of Question

Comment: Then make it `private final QuestionElement[] currentSelections`. You will then see if somewhere you are dereferencing it (making it null).

Comment: I feel like such an idiot.  You're very correct.  I have spent the last three hours trying to figure this out.  I had another method that was updating the variable improperly.  Thank you very much.  I will accept your answer as soon as I am able.  You might want to make an edit stating this method (i.e. set the variable in question to final to see if it is being changed somewhere it shouldn't) in case another idiot like me comes along :).

Comment: immutable objects are always much better to code with, try and create references once and never change them. i.e. `final` constructor dependencies. This will help you a lot! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html